# Angularjs json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Been looking for clues on how to solve this.

Got a json doc with three objects containing arrays of data. Viewing them like:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="x in data.Country
                        | filter:{Continent:ContinentValue}
                        | filter:{GovernmentForm:govForm}
                        | filter:{Name:countName}
                        | orderBy:orderProperty"
                        data-ng-if="x.Population >= popValueMax && x.Population <= popValueMin">
        <td><a href="#/{{ x.Code }}">{{x.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{x.Population}}</td>
        <td>{{x.LifeExpectancy}}</td>
        <td>{{x.GovernmentForm }}</td>
        <td>{{x.HeadOfState }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also using them in another view:

```
<ul >
<li>Local name: {{x.LocalName}}</li>
<li>Continent: {{x.Continent}}</li>
<li>Region: {{x.Region}}</li>
<li>Surface area: {{x.SurfaceArea}}</li>
<li>Population: {{x.Population}}</li>
<li>Gross National Product(GNP): {{x.GNP}}</li>
<li>Government form: {{x.GovernmentForm}}</li>
<li>Head of state: {{x.HeadOfState}}</li>
<li>Capital: {{}}</li>
<li>Official language: {{}}</li>
<li>{{}}</li>
```

In the second one, capital is a number in object A which is X, but the name of the capital is in object B where the capital number from A is the ID of the city in object B.

Using this to get the data between the html docs:

```
controllers.controller("details", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$filter",
function($scope, $routeParams, $filter) {

$scope.x = $filter("filter")($scope.data.Country,
{Code: $routeParams.CodeId})[0];
}]);
```

Any ideas on how to get the name(string) from object B into `<li>Capital: {{}}</li` ?

Comment: FYI - prob unrelated to your problem, but your ng-if in your first code-sample looks suspect. You probably either want an `||` rather than an `&&`, or the `popValueMax` and `popValueMin` are switched. Your code is: `data-ng-if="x.Population >= popValueMax && x.Population <= popValueMin">`

Comment: can you include object B json?

Comment: You can deliver the array json?

Comment: Yes I can deliver the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that object B looks something like

```
[{id:1, name:'One'}, {id:2, name:'Two'}]
```

you can filter the object in you expression and then take the name of the first filtered object.

```
<li>Capital: {{(objectB|filter:{id: x.Capital})[0].name}}</li>
```

If there are more properties on `objectB` that you need to use, you can set the filtered property to a variable and reuse it

```
<li>Capital: {{(capitalObj = (objectB|filter:{id: x.Capital})[0]).name}}</li>
<li>Other Prop: {{capitalObj.other}}</li>
```

Comment: Couldn't get the data with the filter.

Comment: you never included your json. it could this answer is not compatible with it or needs to be adjusted

Comment: obj A: {Capital:"1"Code
:
"AFG"
Code2
:
"AF"
Continent
:
"Asia"
GNP
:
"5976.00"
GNPOld
:
"NULL"
GovernmentForm
:
"Islamic Emirate"
HeadOfState
:
"Mohammad Omar"
IndepYear
:
"1919"
LifeExpectancy
:
"45.9"
LocalName
:
"Afganistan/Afqanestan"
Name
:
"Afghanistan"
Population
:
"22720000"
Region
:
"Southern and Central Asia"
SurfaceArea
:
"652090.00"}

Comment: obj B: {CountryCode
:
"AFG"
District
:
"Qandahar"
ID
:
"2"
Name
:
"Qandahar"
Population
:
"237500"}

Comment: so make sure you use the posted code with proper casing. angular is case-sensitive

Comment: been using: {{(data.City|filter:{ID: x.Capital}).Name}} but no output in html, did I get them in the wrong order?

Comment: see edit. you need to take the first object from the filtered list